# IIS does not recognize the page without .cshtml

Tags: iis, razor, publish, webmatrix

Develop a website with WebMatrix and Razor.
To make the call of the pages I'm using the command:

```
Href("~/Project/Details?ProjectID=" + project.ID)
```

But I IIS returns 404 (not found). If you change the link and place. cshtml after the "Details" getting "... Details.cshtml? ProjectID = 1" oh yes it works.

And this behavior only happens with the site up on my local machine it does not.

I've seen the post here on stackoverflow talking about it, but this is a problem with the on-line (the host) and not local.
So I have no way to reinstall anything

How to solve the problem? How does he understand that without the Outreach pages, he should look for her name + .cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
This may be the problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Try

```
Href("~/Project/Details/?ProjectID=" + project.ID)
```

Note the forward slash prior to the querystring.

Comment: same error.
Following website: http://amsdarquitetura.com.br/
And the page I'm trying to access: http://amsdarquitetura.com.br/Project/Details/?ProjectID=100
The page with the Outreach. cshtml: http://amsdarquitetura.com.br/Project/Details.cshtml?ProjectID=100

Comment: You haven't got the Razor Debugger v 0.1 package installed, have you?

Comment: It's been known to cause the odd problem, but I couldn't remember which ones. Check the link in my updated answer.